# How to check whether the page loaded with the correct url and tab title

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, assert

I wrote a method to load the page navigation links. The method works, but when I added code to check the correct URL and tab title my test is not performed. Sometimes it happens that for loop fast clicks on the pages the side that does not get loaded, I do not know whether it is a problem but I can not check whether a page loaded with the correct url or tab title, or the problem is the code that I wrote for check the correct url or tab title.

This is my method:

```
public void showNavigationLinks(){
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    String[] submenus = {"Accessories", "iMacs", "iPads" , "iPhones" , "iPods" , "MacBook"};

    for(int i=0;i<submenus.length;i++)
    {
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().toLowerCase().contains(submenus[i]));
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains(submenus[i]));

        WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Product Category')]"));
        wait(2000);
        action.moveToElement(we).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'"+submenus[i]+"')]"))).click().build().perform();
        wait(3000);
    }

    link_all_product.click();
}
```

This is my error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed) on port 2140
Only local connections are allowed.
Jan 17, 2017 4:51:23 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Jan 17, 2017 4:51:31 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
    at PageObject.ProductPage.showNavigationLinks(ProductPage.java:620)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error, your Assertion failed!

You are Asserting `...toLowerCase().contains(submenus[i])`. However, every single item in your `submenus` contains **uppercase** characters!

You could change your Assertion to something like `...toLowerCase().contains(submenus[i].toLowerCase())`.

The next problem is going to be: Does your URL, from `driver.getCurrentUrl()` really contain **every single one** of your `submenus` items? I would suspect not! Change your `Assert` to something like:

```
Assert.assertTrue("checking if URL contains: " + submenus[i],
    driver.getCurrentUrl().toLowerCase().contains(submenus[i].toLowerCase()));
```

That way you can see exactly when and why your `Assert` is failing.

Comment: When I run the test, a mistake is the same even though I changed assert: java.lang.AssertionError

Comment: @DyJon I do not understand. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @DyJon Updated my answer to give you additional hints.

Comment: This is my fault: java.lang.AssertionError: checking if URL contains: iMacs It needs time, because sometimes test passes and sometimes falls.

Comment: @DyJon Add one of your `wait()` there. Is this a new question? This is starting to sound like an endless debugging session.